# Infinite loop, page unable to load

Tags: javascript, html, loops, infinite-loop

So it's the same drag and drop game project that I am working on, but I ran into a infinite loop problem, in which I want to use while(backpackLength<5), then the program will run. However, I have no idea where went wrongly, I couldn't even load my page, but I am sure that I am encountering with a infinite loop.
Any suggestion?

```
var backpackLength = 0;

$(function() {
$("#cream").draggable();
$("#charger").draggable();
$("#doll").draggable();
$("#draft").draggable();
$("#folder").draggable();
$("#note").draggable();
while(backpackLength< 5) {
    $("#bag").droppable({
        drop: function() {
            if (registerItem == 1) {
                backpack.push("cream");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#cream").remove();
            }
            if (registerItem == 2) {
                backpack.push("charger");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#charger").remove();
            }

            if (registerItem == 3) {
                backpack.push("doll");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#doll").remove();
            }
            if (registerItem == 4) {
                backpack.push("draft");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#draft").remove();
            }
            if (registerItem == 5) {
                backpack.push("folder");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#folder").remove();
            }
            if (registerItem == 6) {
                backpack.push("note");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#note").remove();
            }
            if (registerItem == 7) {
                backpack.push("pens");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#pens").remove();
            }
            if (registerItem == 8) {
                backpack.push("psp");
                backpackLength++;
                $("#psp").remove();
            }
            if (backpackLength > 0) {
                document.getElementById("bag").src = "minigame/bag2.png";
            }
            if (backpackLength > 4) {
                document.getElementById("bag").src = "minigame/bag3.png";
            }
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if register item isn't equal to any of those things it will just keep running and running you need an else case that breaks the loop

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow, where do I need to put the loop?

Comment: No im saying add an else statement that breaks the loop in case no condition is satisfied that way it wont run so much your program crashes